# How to stop execution of the script if query does not return any result

Tags: php, mysql

In my page I have multiple `company_id`. Some of those did not return any result in the following query.

My question is what should I do for them? Should I leave the code as is or should I stop the execution if there is nothing found? If yes, how can I do this?

```
<?php
   $categories = mysql_query('SELECT distinct(category),id FROM products WHERE company_id = ' . $cid );
   while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)) 
   {
      echo "<a href='#'>" . $cat['category'] . "</a><br>";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not encourage `break`'ing out of the loop, you should be checking that there are rows returned with `mysql_num_rows()` before passing to the loop.

```
<?php
if(isset($cid)){
    $categories = mysql_query('SELECT distinct(category),id FROM products WHERE company_id = ' . $cid );
    if(mysql_num_rows($categories)>=1){
        while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)){
            echo "<a href='#'>" . $cat['category'] . "</a><br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to stop executing in a while loop use break statement

something like

```
while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)) 
{
   if ( $cat['category'] == '' )
      break;                   
   echo "<a href='#'>" . $cat['category'] . "</a><br>";
}
```

keep in mind that this will stop the loop immediately. If you just want to "hide" empty results try something like this

```
while($cat = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories)) 
{
   if ( $cat['category'])            
   echo "<a href='#'>" . $cat['category'] . "</a><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BREAK to get out of the while loop. I am confused though. If the query doesn't return anything, you wouldn't be looping anyway, right?

**EDIT**

It sounds like you might be looping through a set of company_id's in your page and then getting categories for each, right?

```
foreach ($list_companies as $cid)
{
   LOAD CATEGORIES for $cid
   while (have categories)
   {
     echo link to it
   }
}
```

If that's right, then break will get you out of your inner while and onto the next company but, again, if there are no categories, then there's nothing to break out of.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways that always works is the *die()* function

```
if(empty($var)) {
    die();
}
```

or you can add an error message

```
die("No results found!");
```